# update UILabel, get value from NSNumber

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel, nsnumber

I am working on an student budget application. And when user add new expense, label which represent sum of all expenses, should update, but it doesn't.

```
float currentValue = [self.total floatValue];
self.total = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(currentValue + amountValue)];
self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Razem: %@", total];
```

In debuger *total* has a proper value.

Of course when I type something like this

```
self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"something different"];
```

label changed his content.

EDIT.

I've changed code:

```
self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Razem: %@", [total stringValue]];
```

but it updates only once. I've recorded this:
[YT](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tEr347-V6WU)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only change you have to make in your code is to replace 'total' with '[total stringValue]'.

```
self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Razem: %@", [total stringValue]];
```

or try by setting label's text as:

```
[self.label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Razem: %@", [total stringValue]]];
```

Comment: EDIT.

I've changed code:

 self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Razem: %@", [total stringValue]];

but it updates only once. I've recorded this:
[YT][1]


  [1]: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tEr347-V6WU

Comment: it doesn't help. the same result

Comment: I created a sample app for this.Its working fine at my end.Just check that whether the label for atorelease.

Comment: you're right I was allocing UILabel in - (UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section thx for help!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print a float (or a double) you should use "%f" and not "%@"

```
self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Razem: %f", [self.total  floatValue]];
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSNumber` is an object, so `%@` will print its description. To print its value as a float, use `floatValue` and `%f`.

```
self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Razem: %f", [total floatValue]];
```